# Only one resolution available in Xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and when I try to change my resolution in NVIDIA X server settings, I only get the native one (1600x900). When I had 12.04 installed, all resolutions were available in the drop down list. My goal is to have twinview working again. I used to set my two screens to twinview and clones, using my HDTV resolution (1360x768) which was previously available in 12.04 for my laptop screen too.

In 12.10, I tried to install all of the NVIDIA drivers available except the nouveau driver. I tried to add a new mode using `Xrandr --newmode / --addmode`, but it didn't work; it coudn't detect my output. I'd like to know if this is a known bug and if there's something to do with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to work around this problem so far is to manually create a cloned mode from the command line, for example:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="LVDS-0: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +0 +0 {ViewPortIn=1280x1024, ViewPortOut=1440x1080+240+0}, DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select @1280x1024 +0 +0"
```